# include Parse SDK from ios app objective-c error Undefined symbols for architecture i386

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

new to ios development.
used Cocoa Pods to install parse

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'start_learning_ios' do
    pod 'Parse', '~> 1.8'
end

target 'start_learning_iosTests' do

end
```

pod install output (notice the warning):

```
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Bolts (1.2.0)
Using Parse (1.8.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats

[!] The `start_learning_ios [Debug]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-start_learning_ios/Pods-start_learning_ios.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `start_learning_ios [Release]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-start_learning_ios/Pods-start_learning_ios.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

after that I opened the project's `xcworkspace` file.

`AppDelegate.m`

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;
    [Parse setApplicationId:@"ZvSyh5fb19JQLYdK7Vm1wOmE1YNrNB9b79SHoxvg"
                   clientKey:@"9fe7DgwEd3KBvHVvLZFdB7ZGX1bjffvZOKkEJVdP"];
```

note: without `[Parse setAp...]` it builds.
only when trying to use The ParseSDK I get a build error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/partuck/Downloads/parse-osx-library-1.8.0/Bolts.framework/Bolts, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Users/partuck/Downloads/parse-osx-library-1.8.0/Bolts.framework/Bolts
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/partuck/Downloads/parse-osx-library-1.8.0/ParseOSX.framework/ParseOSX, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Users/partuck/Downloads/parse-osx-library-1.8.0/ParseOSX.framework/ParseOSX
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Parse", referenced from:
```

[image: Architectures build settings]

Comment: Do you know where to check the other flags in the target? Is there a reason you have specific flags? Did you open the workspace after pod install?

Comment: yeah, I opened to .xcworkspace file after the install.  specific flags? where do I set it? other flags in the target? no idea where to check..

Comment: Hopefully this image will point you in the correct location http://www.securitylearn.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/xcode-project-code-signing-settings.png

Comment: The underlying problem is that the build architecture doesn't match, somewhere i386 isn't included, or the build is set to current architecture only

Comment: added a screen shot to my build settings, lmk if there is anything missing

Comment: What about the build settings for the parse project pod as that is what the build error relates to (I don't recall if 1.8 is the most recent parse version available, but you should use the newest)

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, I needed to add the binaries to the app:
Build Phases -> Link Binaries -> +  -> Workspace -> libParse.a and libBolt.a 
[image] 
I was stuck on this for 4 days!!!